# MsBuild task does not place native C++ output in TargetOutputs ItemGroup

Tags: c++, msbuild

I just migrated a software containing VC++ (native and managed) projects as well as C# projects from .NET 3.5 to 4.0. We build with MsBuild and we now enjoy the benefits of MsBuild 4.0 which now treats C# and C++ projects the same way. There is one issue however I was unable to solve so far.

I am using TargetOutputs ItemGroup to further process the resulting binaries. This works fine for C# and managed C++ (clr support), but native C++ assemblies (No Common Language Runtime Support) are not placed in this ItemGroup even though the projects are built properly.

This is the statement in use, after that @(MyProjectsOutput) does not contain the native C++ assemblies.

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjects)" Targets="Rebuild" Properties="Platform=x64;Configuration=Release">
  <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="MyProjectsOutput" />
</MSBuild>
```

Any idea what might be the cause? I am pretty stuck here... 
Thanks in advance.

Erik

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, I created an empty C++ console application and this simple MsBuild script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Build" Outputs="" Condition="">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyProjects Include="test\test.vcxproj">
      </MyProjects>
    </ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjects)">
      <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="MyProjectsOutput" />
    </MSBuild>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="MyProjects: @(MyProjects)"></Message>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="MyProjectsOutput: @(MyProjectsOutput)"></Message>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

test.exe was successfully built, but still the ItemGroup @(MyProjectOutput) did not contain the file. When I change test.vcxproj to "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" the output is properly displayed. It appears to be a bug in MsBuild.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GetNativeTargetPath` target name on the MSBuild task to get the output file path of a native C++ project:

```
    <MSBuild Projects="my.vcxproj" Targets="GetNativeTargetPath">
        <Output ItemName="MyOutput" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>
```